# How to set button click listener for Custom Dialog?

Tags: android

I have made a main `Dialog` class on which I send the layout ID and shows the layout as a `Dialog` now when I send the layout from calling class it pops up the dialog but the contents of dialog i.e. buttons are inaccessible I can't set click listener for them. How to do that?

CALLING CLASS:-

```
CustomDialog obj=new CustomDialog(MailSenderActivity.this , R.layout.mydialog);
obj.show();
```

MAIN CLASS

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomDialog extends Dialog implements
View.OnClickListener {
    Dialog dialog;
    int id;


    public CustomDialog(MailSenderActivity mailsender, int id) {
        super(mailsender);
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(id);



        Button signInbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signInButton);

        Button closebutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.closeButton);




        }






    public void closebutton(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You clicked a button!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

id is:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:padding="30dip" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@drawable/gmail">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="296dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1.51" android:layout_height="497dp">
        <TextView android:text="My Dialog" android:textSize="24.5sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"></TextView>
        <TextView android:text="Enter Gmail Id" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/name" android:layout_width="358dp"
            android:singleLine="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </EditText>
        <TextView android:text="Enter Gmail Password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/name" android:layout_width="314dp"
            android:singleLine="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:password="false" android:inputType="textPassword"></EditText>
        <Button android:text="Sign In" android:layout_width="67dp"
            android:id="@+id/signInButton" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true" android:onClick="signIn"></Button>

        <Button android:text="close" android:layout_width="67dp"
            android:id="@+id/closeButton" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true" android:onClick="closeButton"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ok what is the "id" here? and In which xml file the button's are available?

Comment: If you use `onClick="method"` then the `Activity` which pops up the dialog should have that method or otherwise use traditional `setOnClickListener()` on `Button` by getting its Id.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There you go:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(id);

    Button signInbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signInButton);
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button closebutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.closeButton);
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(R.id.closeButton == v.getId()) { 
        closeButton(v);
    } else {

    // do the same for signInButton
    }

}
```

Suggest you learn the basic beforehand.

Comment: it worked ..thanx a lot sir...i am a beginner in android will look forward towards your suggestion

Comment: great! you can visit my site for a start of learning/studying android with lots of simple tutorials: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/

Comment: well thanx for the site sir, but can u help me with this sir...                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525851/how-to-add-a-line-as-a-gesture-while-moving-from-one-image-to-another

Comment: How can we use this listener in our MainActivity class?

Answer (score 11):

```
 dialog_bring_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

              final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);
              dialog.setContentView(R.layout.MyCustomDialogxmlfile);

              dialog.show(); 

            /* My Cancel Button , and its listener */

              my_cancel_btn=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.datesetbtn);
              my_cancel_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                     dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

I find that the code is clearer to seperate my click handlers.  Add this in the onCreate method:

```
signInbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     // do stuff for signInButtonClick
  }
});

// same for other button
```

Comment: it shows an error saying --> The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})

Comment: Ah.  It looks like you've imported the wrong OnClickListener.  I'll update my example to make it more explict.

Answer (score 1):

```
dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");


Button dialog_btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button);
dialog_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    // Perform button logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In 2019 this work for me. You can change text view with button.

```
  Dialog mdialog = new Dialog(this);
      mdialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_type);
        mdialog.show();
TextView view = mdialog.findViewById(R.id.viewQuotes);
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Working...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
           {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
                   {                   
         CustomDialog dialog1 = new CustomDialog(Classname.this);
                  dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.submitdialog);
                  dialog1.setTitle(" SUBMIT :");
                TextView text = (TextView) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.message);
                  text.setText("  Your Answer is correct  ");
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warning);
    builder.setTitle("Warning");

    final LinearLayout backAlarmDialogLayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.custumedialog_layou, null);
    builder.setView(backAlarmDialogLayout);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    backAlarmDialog = builder.create();
```

Set these codes to initialize your costumed dialog in onCreate like this, and if you would like to add listener to your button, you can write another method like

```
  public void onClickCancel(View view){
    backAlarmDialog.dismiss();
}
```

then you use

```
android:onClick="onClickCancel"
```

in the button in the XML.files you have costumed the dialog, I have tried other ways but they just would not work and I don not know why is this.Maybe someone would solve mine. ||= =