# Where have I to define the onclick for button in customized dialog?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, onclicklistener, android-dialogfragment

I got a dialog created in a `DialogFragment`. This works fine.

For my dialog I use a customized layout. This contains two buttons.

*release_scan_dialog.xml*

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/code"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Scan 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/storageplace"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Scan 2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*ScanFragment.java*

```java
public class ScanFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public android.app.Dialog onCreateDialog(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity())
            .setView(this.getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.release_scan_dialog, null))
            .setTitle(R.string.title_store)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .create();

            dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

                @Override
                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
                }
            });

            // This will crush with a NullPointerException
            dialog.findViewById(R.id.code).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        return dialog;
    }
}
```

If I try to define the `onClick` for the both buttons a `NullPointerException` occurs. Which is the correct event to implement the `onClick`?

Thanks for any response.

Comment: did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657755/how-to-set-button-click-listener-for-custom-dialog) questions, for example?

Comment: I read this and this case is different to my. I use a `DialogFragment` and not a `Dialog`. I created my dialog like the example from the Android Developer page http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `code` button can be found within the view inflated from the `release_scan_dialog` layout.

```
public class ScanFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public android.app.Dialog onCreateDialog(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the view for the release_scan_dialog layout.
        final View release_scan_view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.release_scan_dialog, null);

        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity())
            .setView(release_scan_view)
            .setTitle(R.string.title_store)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .create();

            dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

                @Override
                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
                }
            });

            // Set the OnClickListener for the 'code' button in the release_scan_dialog layout.
            release_scan_view.findViewById(R.id.code).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going to write the same thing but since you answered first, upvoting you. Simple but common mistake.