# Button Click Event for Dialog from XML in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-dialog

am working on an application which has lot of button in the dialog(like keyboard). I need to get the text of the click button and assign to variable. I created a common function here(showtoast). but when I click on the button in the popup, it is unfortunately stopped. showing like no such method. if I rise the event from java means, there is no such problem.
Example:

```
buttona.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                                  
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Button b = (Button)v;
    String text = b.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button clicked is" + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity .java

```
package com.example.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Context c = this;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        showdialog();
    }

    private void showdialog() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(c);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);

        dialog.show();
    }
    public void showtoast(View v)
    {
        Button b = (Button)v;
        String text = b.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button clicked is" + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="showtoast"
        android:text="a"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="showtoast"
        android:text="b"
        />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="showtoast"
        android:text="c"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

LOG:

```
01-28 12:05:17.386: E/AndroidRuntime(7875): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method showtoast(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button
```

please anyone help to rise the event from xml for buttons in dialog or any other solution.

Comment: Use `MainActivity.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` to create `Dialog` object and also add log with question to get more help

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657755/how-to-set-button-click-listener-for-custom-dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657755/how-to-set-button-click-listener-for-custom-dialog)

Answer (score 2):

### popup.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:text="c"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
private void showdialog() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(c);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
    final Button b = (Button)dialog.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.b);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"one", 2000).show();
                
            }
        });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly call the method of activity from the dialog for that you need to implement a listener & a custom dialog class.

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {

    public CustomDialog(Context context, String title,
            final ItemReturnListener listener) {
        super(context, R.style.CustomDialog);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom);

        Button tvDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        Button tvName = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        Button tvPrice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);

        tvDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                listener.returnString(tvDate.getText().toString());
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        tvName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                listener.returnString(tvName.getText().toString());
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        tvPrice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                listener.returnString(tvPrice.getText().toString());
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    }
```

now open dialog by calling this method

```
private void openDialog() {
        dialog = new CustomDialog(MainActivity.this, new ItemReturnListener() {

            @Override
            public void returnString(String str) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button clicked is" + str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
```

Create Interface like this

```
public interface ItemReturnListener {
    void returnString(String str);
}
```