# How to make an object not visible after drawing line across it?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I know the codes for drawing lines while onTouch ACTION_DOWN but I don't know what code to use to make an image fade after drawing a line on top.

What I want to do is something similar to Fruit Ninja, but just making the image fade.

Comment: Please show the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dead simple fade out animation.

```
  public void animate(){
        View myView = //The view that you want to animate (initialize it)
        Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        myView.startAnimation(out);
        myView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
```

Note: the above code resides in an activity so `this` refers to a `context`

Look at the [Animation Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) for more details.  It goes into a lot of detail.

Update:

Determining whether the line was drawn over an object will require some work. You can start by looking at [Gestures](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/index.html).  You will need to implement `onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event)` with `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE`, `ACTION_UP`.  You mentioned that you already know how to draw a line. So you will need to put in some logic to determine if the line was drawn over your object.

Borrowing information from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525851/how-to-add-a-line-as-a-gesture-while-moving-from-one-image-to-another):

You can get coordinate by using `event.getX()` `event.getY()` before and after the line was drawn and then determine whether the coordinates overlap with your view.

Good luck!

Comment: Can you give me a condition that determines if the user draw a line on top of that object?